# Date format in Hive 03-MAR-14 12:00:00

Tags: date, hive, format

I have the following string in Hive as 03-MAR-14 12:00:00 which needs to be converted to a timestamp  as 2014-03-03 12:00:00. Any idea about how to do it in one query

Comment: Did you check the [Hive Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select '03-MAR-14 12:00:00', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('03-MAR-14 12:00:00','dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss');
```

You should read a little bit about [Hive Date Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) though.

Hope this help you.

Comment: DO you think  it is that easy ? Did you try to execute it before suggesting others?

Comment: Hi @Peter2711. I made sure that piece of code work and it actually works and solves what you asked. Did you execute it?

Comment: Hi I did execute it but it does not work in Horton what Hive version you are using ?

Comment: Hello @Peter2711, The vHive version I am using is: Apache Hive (version 1.1.0-cdh5.4.7).